# Firebase Realtime Database in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, firebase-console

Like Firebase Firestore in Firebase console, the same data is present in Firestore in Google Cloud Platform, similarly where is Firebase Realtime Database (json file) found in Google Cloud Platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database is only available in the Firebase console. It does not exist in the Google Cloud console.